# Package-specific utils::news() not working in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to bring up news for a package while in RStudio. While the default `utils::news()` works for generating the base R changelog in the built-in viewer, I can't get it to work for a specific package; it throws an error. The function works fine for specific packages in RGui.

Fresh R session in RStudio 1.2.1335:

```r
news() # this works
news(package = "ggplot2") # this doesn't
```

Error that I get in viewer: `Error in UseMethod("toHTML") : no applicable method for 'toHTML' applied to an object of class "NULL"`

Fresh R session in RGui:

```r
news()
news(package = "ggplot2") # both work perfectly
```

Session info:

```r
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0 tools_3.6.0    Rcpp_1.0.1     xml2_1.2.0     commonmark_1.7
```

How can I get the function to output without error in RStudio? If this is not possible, how can I run the function in RStudio but tell it to view the HTML outside of the viewer, e.g., in the browser like RGui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an RStudio bug, so probably the best action is to report it to them.  As a workaround, you can avoid using their built-in browser by changing the setting for `options("browser")`.

For example, on a Mac outside of RStudio I see

```
options("browser")
# $browser
# [1] "/usr/bin/open"
```

and in RStudio running

```
options(browser = "/usr/bin/open")
```

disables the built-in browser.   I don't know what it defaults to in RGui on Windows, but setting it to the same in RStudio as it is in RGui should get it to work.

Unfortunately, this disables it for everything, not just for `news()`, so you probably want something like this instead:

```
save <- options(browser = "/usr/bin/open")
news(package = "ggplot2")
options(save)
```

Comment: Your solution works on Windows so I am marking it solved, thank you. However, I discovered something else weird: upon switching to a Mac, any package that has its news in a `NEWS.md` returns `NULL` for `news(package = "thatpackage")`. True enough, the documentation for `news` does not include `NEWS.md` files among the extensions it is capable of processing *on Mac*, but on Windows it is there provided you have `commonmark` and `xml2` installed. Trying a package that has a raw `NEWS` file on Mac, such as `corrplot`, works.

Comment: I think `ggplot2` uses `NEWS.md`, and it works for me on my Mac.  I did need to install the `commonmark` package, and I already had `xml2` installed.  I forget what the message was that prompted the `commonmark` installation.